TV series about futuristic earth where brutal ruler rules
I remember watching a TV series on Bindass or its sister channel about a Futuristic earth (looks like de-evolved) in Hindi dubbed language may be 5-6 years ago. Where a Brutal King rules a large land. He has a daughter who dislikes her father and even started hating him as the story progress. 
She always struggles to find about her mother and she might have a step brother too. In starting episodes of the story his daughter stated liking a poor funny man, who entertains her and make her happy but his father kills him. Even their is one of her father's prisoner gives her hint about his father's deeds and about his mother too. 
There is one assistant to this King who have hidden motives and even manipulates the prophesies made by some people who tells the future in some other language which king doesn't know. This future telling people uses weird makeup on there faces.
One prophesies is about a hero which makes king insecure (I don't exectly remember that prophesies  but its about the fall of king due to that man). That hero works with a girl and even king's daughter also helps her in some scenes.
The hero came from other place and unaware of what going on and he comes near to a girl which helps her know things. The king's one problem is the lack of water in his place and try get it from a place of Ice and got struggled. And story goes on. 
So anybody know which series is it. 

It sounds like Flash Gordon, (2007).  From Wikipedia:

Mongo is ruled by the ruthless dictator Ming (John Ralston), who
  controls "Source Water", the only source of safe drinking water on
  Mongo.

...

Ming has a daughter, Princess Aura (Anna van Hooft), who is disturbed
  by her father's brutality. The series adds a new non-Terran character,
  Baylin (Karen Cliche), a bounty hunter from Mongo. She finds herself
  trapped on Earth and becomes a comrade of Flash, Dale and Zarkov and
  their guide to Mongo and its inhabitants.

...

The peoples of Mongo live in "cantons", tribal groups that echo the
  animal-human hybrids of the original comic strip. The cantons include
  [...] the Zurn (painted blue "Magic Men" led by Queen Azura). There is
  also another group known as the Deviates, mutants whose ancestors
  drank "Grey Water" (toxic water) to survive. The Deviates are led by
  Terek, their unofficial king (and Aura's brother) and are distrusted
  by almost everyone.

I think the King's assistant you refer to was a "Zurn".  The Princess's mother was locked away in secret by the King because he accuses her of drinking "Grey Water", which led to their son's mutation.  In reality it was he who drank the "Grey Water".

That's it. How can i forgot Mongo. I got confuse between mongo and earth.
